# Не собирается проект на flutter ни в android studio, ни в xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

проект на flutter не копилится, ноутбук - macbook air m1

в Xcode [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в android studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]